# Multiple Scanner for multiple file stream?

Tags: java.util.scanner

Hi I need to read multiple .bib files (they are texts), and I need to pretty much search in those.

I'm wondering if I need multiple scanners, one for each file?

Or do I do one Scanner for all and for every new file I point to a new reference file.

What is the better practice?

Comment: How would you make the `Scanner` point to a new reference file without creating a new `Scanner`?

Comment: in a for loop. like this:Scanner bib=null; for(File f:filesInDir) {
   try {
    
    bib=new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
   }

Comment: That still creates a new `Scanner` object. It just will assign it to the variable `bib`

Comment: wait so does it mean if I do this I'm opening several scanners and not properly closing them?